# How resolution can be increased in a hyper-v virtual machine of windows 8

Tags: linux, windows, hyper-v, virtual-machines, opensuse

i already have Windows 8 from MSDNAA. I'm very interested in Hyper-V, so i've created an hyper-v virtual machine with openSUSE. If i connect, i have only a 800x600 resolution. I have not found any resolution settings. If you ever be able to change it?

best regards,

Answer (score 2):

That's something you need to ask of somebody who understands openSUSE.  You change resolutions like you would on a physical machine.

Comment: i'm not sure, but in openSUSE i h've no resolution settings too - only 800x600. in my opinion vm brings the (max)resolution-setting to vm.

Comment: That could easily be.  The Hyper-V VM projects a generic VGA into the VM.  The intent is to allow a console that's good enough to get Remote Desktop or equivalent technologies working.  Use networking to connect to the machine.